# Sub-links missing in "current navigation"

Tags: navigation, current-navigation

A strange bug is occurring with the "Current Navigation" feature, whereby for some users (on all browsers), the sub-links (second level link) within the "Current Navigation" aren't appearing when the page loads, preventing users from navigating the site. They flash for an instance, but then disappear after half a second. Really strange because this is isolated to only a couple of users!

Editing the list displays all the links, and all are set as visible.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: possibly some css or js in the page? advise to inspect the page and check

Comment: Are those users in some SP group? so maybe somebody hid them on purpose from them.

Comment: This is affecting site owners as well so it’s not group related. Will check the CSS JS for any hidden properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation we found that screens with resolution of 1280x1024 was to blame for the sub-links disapearing. Found that zooming browser out to 90% on this resolution will allow the sub-links to appear